# Error with ternary operator in PHP code sniffer

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I have problem with PHP code sniffer and ternary operator.
I added rule for checking spaces after and before operators

```
<rule ref="Squiz.WhiteSpace.OperatorSpacing"/>
```

and now I have errors in short if statements:

```
 37 | ERROR | [x] Expected 1 space before "?"; newline found
 38 | ERROR | [x] Expected 1 space before ":"; newline found
```

My code looks like:

```
return ($this->get('router')->getContext()->getHttpPort() == 80)
    ? '//'.$this->get('router')->getContext()->getHost()
    : '//'.$this->get('router')->getContext()->getHost().':'.$this->get('router')->getContext()->getHttpPort();
```

Anyone know where can be problem? I can paste whole ruleset file but after delete OperatorSpacing rule everything is ok.

Greetings

Comment: Well, the error seems pretty self-explanatory, the system was expecting a space before each of your operators, but found a newline. Replace them with single spaces and it should work.

Comment: More info on this intended feature here : https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/348

Comment: Squiz has standards you have to follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks for help but i found solution, @roberto06, thanks for link m8!

After add

```
<rule ref="Squiz.WhiteSpace.OperatorSpacing">
    <properties>
        <property name="ignoreNewlines" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

it's working perfect :)

Comment: Could you please mark your answer as accepted? So we all know this question is resolved, thanks

Comment: @TomášVotruba Done :)

Answer (score 1):

It only says everything should be on the same line.

By the way, something better in your case would be:

```
$value = '//'.$this->get('router')->getContext()->getHost();

return $value . ($this->get('router')->getContext()->getHttpPort() !== 80) ? (':'.$this->get('router')->getContext()->getHttpPort()) : '';
```